# Can I mix CSS and SCSS on the same style sheet?

Tags: css, sass

I have just found SCSS and am thinking it would be useful on a site I am currently developing (I'm about 50% done) and that it would be a good way to make some of my existing CSS tidier and easier to read.

My question is can I rewrite parts of my existing CSS as SCSS and leave the rest as CSS?  Can I have both CSS and SCSS in the same stylesheet or does it have to be all SCSS or CSS?

Comment: Next time you start learning something new, see the documentation first. You can see the answer to your question in the Syntax section of the index page of the Sass documentation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCSS is a pre-processor of CSS, so yes you can mix, as long you use the files ending in `.scss`

Although I advise you to read the [SASS Docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) and use it in a proper way.

see this below and the [SASS demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/4d1a44b77dbbfec1bfb17ced88b2d3bb):

SCSS

```
.test {
  div {
    color:red;
  }
}

div span {
  background:blue;
}
```

CSS

```
.test div {
  color: red;
}

div span {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, that's perfectly fine, no problem.